# Same const type qualifier

Tags: c++, constants, typedef

Having two `const`'s for a type issues a warning / error. However if the type has been defined with `typedef`, the compiler accepts it (both Visual Studio 2013 and the online compiler C++ shell).

```
#include <iostream>

typedef const int value_type;

int main()
{
    const value_type  n = 0;   //ok 
    const const int   n2 = 0;  //error C4114

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why? Is it that one is `const (const int)`, which is different from `const const int`?

Comment: This code is OK, what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's explicitly allowed in the typedef case, and disallowed in the declaration itself:

[[dcl.type/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type#1)

> The type-specifiers are:
>
> *type-specifier* : ... *cv-qualifier*
>   ***defining-type-specifier*** : *type-specifier*

[[dcl.spec/1 and 2]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.spec#2)

> The specifiers that can be used in a declaration are:
>
> *decl-specifier* : ... ***defining-type-specifier*** ...
>
> **Each decl-specifier shall appear at most once in a complete
>   decl-specifier-seq, except that long may appear twice.**

[[dcl.type.cv/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.cv#1)

> There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. **Each cv-qualifier
>   shall appear at most once in a cv-qualifier-seq**. If a cv-qualifier
>   appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the init-declarator-list or
>   member-declarator-list of the declaration shall not be empty. [ Note:
>   [basic.type.qualifier] and [dcl.fct] describe how cv-qualifiers affect
>   object and function types.  — end note ] **Redundant cv-qualifications
>   are ignored. [ Note: For example, these could be introduced by
>   typedefs. — end note ]**

Besides type aliases, a template parameter is another case where the qualifier could be redundant. The rationale for allowing this, is to not break otherwise correct declarations just because a cv-qualifier snuck in the back door.

Comment: I'm impressed: you memorised the standard?!

Comment: @Bathsheba - Only the index :) Everything else is a very fuzzy recollection.

Comment: Thx that seems to be the case. The C++ standard is really hard to read for myself though.

Comment: StoryTeller is a hashtable: confirmed.

Comment: @gast128 - It's hard to read period. But it does get easier with practice, so I encourage you to keep on trying.

Comment: @Quentin - This comment of mine is highly inappropriate given SO's policy. But I felt you should know I almost squirted my coffee through my nose when I read your comment. ^_^

Comment: That's the wrong quote for the "disallowed" part. There is no *cv-qualifier-seq* in OP's example. You want the analogous rule for *decl-specifier-seq*s a couple paragraphs above.

Comment: @T.C. - I must say that it's spread out over quite a bit of paragraph. But now added.

Answer (score 0):

Last change to get rid of is **Solution** wide **Disable**

- C/C++
- - Advanced
- - - **Disable Specific Warnings**: **4114**

In XML then looks like

```
...
    <DisableSpecificWarnings>4114</DisableSpecificWarnings>
</ClCompile>
```

or line parameter shows /wd"4114"